# Which parts of ElasticSearch.NET client should be kept around for SniffingConnectionPool to work?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

My goal is to ensure that sniffing only happens on the preset interval:

```
.SniffLifeSpan(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5))
```

But right now it seems to refresh the nodelist on every reqeust. My connectionpool is static:

```
private static readonly Lazy<SniffingConnectionPool> connectionPool
```

But thats the only thing that I keep around per. request - should the client itself be kept?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the client itself is thread-safe. So keeping the client around would be an option:

From http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/nest-and-elasticsearch-net-1-3/

Remember: The client is thread-safe, so you can use a single client ...

Answer (score 1):

Hanging on to the connection pool is now enough in 1.4.2+

https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-net/commit/56a629dd9cd993f42da7379b629d4a35cf6f4da4